NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' available
I am trying to get the OAuth2 client going for client credentials grant type and am following the new features released in 6.4 mentioned here https://spring.io/blog/2024/10/28/restclient-support-for-oauth2-in-spring-security-6-4
I am finding that OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is not available as mentioned here https://spring.io/blog/2024/10/28/restclient-support-for-oauth2-in-spring-security-6-4#:~:text=Spring%20Security%20provides,in%20our%20application.
Error encountered

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' in your configuration.

....

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.510 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests
[ERROR] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads -- Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@59cda16e testClass = com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.example.demo.DemoApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@663c9e7a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6bbe85a8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3f191845, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@5524cca1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizerFactory$OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizer@353352b6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@43df23d3, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a2815468], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:160)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restClientConfig' defined in file [/Users/viswanathgnanasekaranuma/projects/oauth2client/target/classes/com/example/demo/RestClientConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.instantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1461)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1589)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:913)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 45 more

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@59cda16e testClass = com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.example.demo.DemoApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@663c9e7a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6bbe85a8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3f191845, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@5524cca1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizerFactory$OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizer@353352b6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@43df23d3, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a2815468], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

my RestClientConfig
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.client.OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClient;

@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

  private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;
  private RestClient restClient;

  public RestClientConfig(@Autowired OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    this.authorizedClientManager = authorizedClientManager;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  void initialize() {
    OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor =
        new OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor(authorizedClientManager);
    this.restClient =
        RestClient.builder()
            .messageConverters(
                (messageConverters) -> {
                  messageConverters.clear();
                  messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
                  messageConverters.add(new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter());
                })
            .defaultStatusHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler())
            // TODO: Customize the instance of RestClient as needed...
            .requestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public RestClient restClient() {
    return this.restClient;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest>
  authorizationCodeAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    RestClientAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
        new RestClientAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestClient(this.restClient);

    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2RefreshTokenGrantRequest>
  refreshTokenAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    RestClientRefreshTokenTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
        new RestClientRefreshTokenTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestClient(this.restClient);

    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest>
  clientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    RestClientClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
        new RestClientClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestClient(this.restClient);

    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<JwtBearerGrantRequest>
  jwtBearerAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    RestClientJwtBearerTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
        new RestClientJwtBearerTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestClient(this.restClient);

    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<TokenExchangeGrantRequest>
  tokenExchangeAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    RestClientTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
        new RestClientTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestClient(this.restClient);

    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }
}

